# Why Dictionary of widgets does not update when deleting CTkEntry Widgets?

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter, customtkinter

NOTE: This is a code I used in a previous question for different reasons.

I have created a window that contains a table(frame) with Entry widgets, Label widgets, checkbox widgets and button widgets using for-loops. The window also has two buttons (outside the table) that allow the user to either insert new rows or delete them. This works fine.

However, the function that inserts a new row updated the widget dictionary, while the other function(delete row function) does not update the widget dictionary. I added `print(_entry)` at the end of both functions for you to see the difference

I do no know why it does not update it. I have tried by adding a `return` inside the `delete()` function, but it does not seem to be working.

I'd very much appreciate your help on this

See code below:

```
import customtkinter


customtkinter.FontManager.load_font("Industry-Book.otf")
customtkinter.FontManager.load_font("Industry-Medium.otf")
customtkinter.FontManager.load_font("Industry-Demi.otf")


def append():
    global row, rows,currenth
    row = rows
    for column in range(columns):
        index = (row, column)
        e = customtkinter.CTkEntry(framedash, validate="key",justify='c',fg_color='#27333B',border_color='#D1D3D4')#, validatecommand=self.vcmd)
        e.grid(row=row+1, column=column+1, stick="nsew")
        _entry[index] = e
    l1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(framedash, text=row + 1, font=("Industry-Medium", 14),bg_color='#8F8F8F',width=40)  # setting a lable/text
    l1.grid(row=row+1, column=0, columnspan=1, padx=1, pady=1,stick="nsew")
    cb = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(framedash, text='', width=0)
    cb.grid(row=row + 1, column=5, columnspan=1, padx=1, pady=1, stick="nsew")
    downbutton = customtkinter.CTkButton(framedash, text='DW', width=20, height=20,command=lambda  row=row:down(row))
    downbutton.grid(row=row + 1, column=6, columnspan=1, padx=1, pady=1, stick="nsew")
    upbutton = customtkinter.CTkButton(framedash, text='UP', width=20, height=20,command=lambda row=row:up(row))
    upbutton.grid(row=row + 1, column=7, columnspan=1, padx=1, pady=1, stick="nsew")

    _entry1[index] = l1
    _entry2[index] = cb
    _entry3[index] = downbutton
    _entry4[index] = upbutton

    currenth = currenth + 30
    dashboard.geometry(f'450x{currenth}')
    rows += 1
    print(_entry)



def addrow():
    append()


def delete(): #THIS IS THE FUNCTION THAT DOES NOT UPDATE THE _entry dictionary
    global row, rows, currenth
    if rows==1:
        return False
    else:
        row = rows-1
        for column in range(columns):
            index = (row, column)
            _entry[index].grid_remove()
        _entry1[index].grid_remove()
        _entry2[index].grid_remove()
        _entry3[index].grid_remove()
        _entry4[index].grid_remove()
        currenth = currenth - 30
        dashboard.geometry(f'450x{currenth}')
        rows -= 1
        print(_entry)

def deleterow():
    delete()


currenth=380
dashboard = customtkinter.CTk(fg_color='#27333b')
dashboard.geometry(f"450x{currenth}") #size of window
dashboard.title('Itipack Systems Cals') #tittle of the window
dashboard.attributes('-topmost', True)  # note - before topmost
dashboard.resizable(False, False)
dashboard.after(201, lambda: dashboard.iconbitmap('Itipack_icon_cmyk_rev_l.ico'))

_entry = {}
_entry1 = {}
_entry2 = {}
_entry3 = {}
_entry4 = {}
rows=9
columns =2
table = [columns,rows]

framedash = customtkinter.CTkFrame(dashboard,width=600,height=600,fg_color='#27333b')
framedash.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=10,pady=10,columnspan=columns+4,rowspan=rows+1,sticky='')


c1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(framedash,text='FUNCTION',font=("Industry-Medium",14),bg_color='grey',width=60) #setting a lable/text
c1.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=1, padx=1, pady=1,sticky='nesw') #location?

c2 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(framedash,text='DURATION',font=("Industry-Medium",14),bg_color='grey',width=40) #setting a lable/text
c2.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=1, padx=1, pady=1,sticky='nesw') #location?



for row in range(rows):
    l1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(framedash, text=row+1, font=("Industry-Medium",14),bg_color='#8F8F8F',width=40)  # setting a lable/text
    l1.grid(row=row+1, column=0, columnspan=1, padx=1, pady=1, stick="nsew")
    cb= customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(framedash,text='',width=0)
    cb.grid(row=row+1, column=5, columnspan=1, padx=1, pady=1, stick="nsew")
    downbutton = customtkinter.CTkButton(framedash,text='DW',width=20,height=20,command=lambda  row=row:down(row)) #lamda expression to give the command to every button
    downbutton.grid(row=row + 1, column=6, columnspan=1, padx=1, pady=1, stick="nsew")
    upbutton = customtkinter.CTkButton(framedash,text='UP',width=20,height=20,command=lambda row=row:up(row))
    upbutton.grid(row=row + 1, column=7, columnspan=1, padx=1, pady=1, stick="nsew")

    for column in range(columns):
        index = (row, column)
        e = customtkinter.CTkEntry(framedash, validate="key",justify='c',fg_color='#27333B',border_color='#D1D3D4')#, #validatecommand=self.vcmd)
        e.grid_configure(row=row+1, column=column+1,padx=1, pady=1, stick="nsew")
        _entry[index] = e
    _entry1[index] = l1
    _entry2[index] = cb
    _entry3[index]= downbutton
    _entry4[index]=upbutton

# adjust column weights so they all expand equally
for column in range(columns):
    framedash.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=0)
# designate a final, empty row to fill up any extra space
framedash.grid_rowconfigure(rows, weight=0)

button1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(dashboard, width=50, height=50, text='A', font=("Industry-Medium", 16),
                                  corner_radius=1, fg_color='#00AAE9',
                                  command=addrow)  # , command=calculate)
button1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='e')


button1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(dashboard, width=50, height=50, text='D', font=("Industry-Medium", 16),
                                  corner_radius=1, fg_color='#00AAE9',
                                  command=deleterow)  # , command=calculate)
button1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='w')

button1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(dashboard, width=50, height=50, text='S', font=("Industry-Medium", 16),
                                  corner_radius=1, fg_color='#00AAE9')  # , command=calculate)
button1.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

label12=customtkinter.CTkEntry(dashboard,width=50,height=30,justify='c')
label12.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=5, pady=5,sticky='w')

label12=customtkinter.CTkLabel(dashboard,text='# STRAPS',font=("Industry-Medium", 16))
label12.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=5, pady=5,sticky='e')

dashboard.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
dashboard.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
dashboard.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
dashboard.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
dashboard.grid_columnconfigure(4, weight=1)
dashboard.grid_columnconfigure(5, weight=1)
dashboard.mainloop()
```

Comment: Calling `.grid_remove()` just remove the widget from the MMI, it still exists in the dictionary.

Comment: yes, i thought so. How can I also remove/update the values in the dictionary? @acw1668

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `.grid_remove()` will only remove the widget from the MMI and the widget still exists in the dictionary.

You can use `.pop(index)` to remove and return the widget from the dictionary, and then call `.destroy()` to destroy the widget.

```py
def delete():
    global row, rows, currenth
    if rows==1:
        return False
    else:
        row = rows-1
        for column in range(columns):
            index = (row, column)
            _entry.pop(index).destroy()
        _entry1.pop(index).destroy()
        _entry2.pop(index).destroy()
        _entry3.pop(index).destroy()
        _entry4.pop(index).destroy()
        currenth = currenth - 30
        dashboard.geometry(f'450x{currenth}')
        rows -= 1
        print(_entry)
```